# Creating a java makefile for several .java files (ubuntu)

Tags: java, ubuntu, makefile

My java makefile currently looks like this:

main:
    javac userCreatedClass.java userCreatedClass2.java mainClass.java

After running 'make' in the terminal, I end up with a .class file for each of the .java files. My question is how do I now run my java program from the terminal? If there was only one .java file to begin with, at this point, in the terminal, I could enter

> > java Prog

and it would run my program. How would I be able to do this since I have multiple classes?

Comment: Aside of your problem (answered below by someone else), you should consider respecting [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html).

Comment: Consider that if all java files are part of one program, just one of them should have a main(). So you have just to specify the name of your program entrypoint (the class declaring a main).

Answer (score 1):

You only need to specify the class with the

```
public static void main(String[] args) {...
```

method.  After that the JVM handles loading the classes you need for you.  You may, however want to put the files in a subfolder named e.g. "somethng" and then use "package something" in each of the java files (but still compile from the top folder).  This will save you from some subtle issues later.

Answer (score 0):

You specify the class contining the static `main` method. So in your case most likely

```
java mainClass
```